# Does MSBuild always copies nuget PackageReference of csproj files to the build output directory?

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

In the net core world, you have to invoke the publish command to bring the assemblies, referenced through nuget, into your projects output directory.

In the .NET Framework world, there is no publish command. My assumption was that msbuild always resolves the referenced nuget packages and copies the assemblies to the output directory. On my developer machine this works always.

Now we see problems that this does not happen during an automated build and colleagues started to add references with the [GeneratePathProperty](https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/a-better-way-to-override-references-with-packagereference/) and do an explicit copy action with CopyToOutputDirectory. In my eyes that's wrong and error prone because transitive dependencies are not resolved automatically.

Can someone point me to a piece of msbuild documentation which explains the nuget handling?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer, I didn't read your question properly. You are correct about the copy behaviour in core vs framework though, and adding `GeneratePathProperty` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do in general, and shouldn't have any impact on the copy behaviour at all. Are you using `PackageReference` or `Reference` in your projects?

Comment: We reference nuget packages with the **PackageReference** tag.